# CS5001:Does not have an entry point defined

Tags: c#

Why do I get a CS5001: does not have an entry point defined error when compiling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common problem is that you used a lowercase ‘m’ when defining the Main method. The correct way to implement the entry point is as follows:

```
class test 
{
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
    } 
}
```